# Escaping apostrophes in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, escaping, apostrophe, stripslashes

I wrote a plugin for wordpress that stores restaurant menu items. But whenever apostrophes are used, wordpress escapes them with slashes on both the admin and front end and keeps adding slashes to the text on every save.

This is an excerpt and example of what I have as post code:

```
$dinnerEntree2 = $_POST[$dinnerEntree_option];
for ($i=1; $i<= $dinner_menu_item_number_saved; $i++) {

// entree   dinner_menu_entree_option
$dinnerEntree = "dinner_menu_".$i."_entree";
$dinnerEntree_saved = "dinner_menu_".$i."_entree_save";
$dinnerEntree_option = "dinner_menu_".$i."_entree_option";
$dinnerEntree_saved2 = get_option($ingredients);
$dinnerEntree2 = $_POST[$dinnerEntree_option];

if ($dinnerEntree_saved2 != $dinnerEntree2)
if(!update_option($dinnerEntree,$dinnerEntree2))
$message='failed to save large entree';
// end of entree
```

and in the input form field:

```
<input type="text" name="dinner_menu_<?php echo $i ?>_entree_option" value="<?php echo get_option($dinnerEntree);  ?>" size="40"/></span>
```

I have tried stripslashes, but have had no luck. This has been discussed over the years but i have seen no definitive solution for wordpress. Magic Quotes are off on my server.... any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
$dinnerEntree2 = stripslashes_deep( $_POST[$dinnerEntree_option] );
```

Reference: [`stripslashes_deep()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/stripslashes_deep)

Note: it should be used before any (and not within) commands which interact with `$wpdb`.

Comment: Thanks - but still no success. This is a difficult one to solve. Lots of googling has not helped me yet, which is why I decided to post to this great site.

Comment: If the entries in the database are already riddled with too many slashes (e.g. `\\\\\\\\'`), you might have to manually remove them before trying `stripslashes_deep()` again.

Comment: No slashes in database... admin plugin does remove them